How to compile tensorflow serving (tensorflow/xla) to have llvm/mlir as shared objects rather than statically included in the binary?
I am trying to compile the tensorflow serving project and I would like to
have llvm/mlir compiled as a shared objects.
The project is tensorflow serving -> tensorflow -> xla and compiles to a huge
binary that is mostly static.
I would like to be able to compile llvm and mlir as shared objects.
I have tried setting linkstatic = False, in as many places where I could.
They only place in which it has an effect is in tensorflow_serving/model_servers/BUILD
in the tensorflow_model_server rule:
cc_binary(
    name = "tensorflow_model_server",
    linkstatic = False,

The resul of adding linkstatic = False, is a binary with all the libraries
dynamically linked (around 2030 libraries).
I also tried setting linkshared = True in many places.
So far I was not able to follow the flow of the compilation process and see
where the rules for compiling llvm and mlir.
Trying to follow the bazel files as much as I could, I think the compilation
flow is something like this:
tensorflow serving
  └── tensorflow text
      └── tensorflow (should include llvm/mlir)
          └── xla    (should include llvm/mlir)

but I am not able to see where and how llvm is compiled.
The ideal situation would be to have libLLVM.so and libMLIR.so that are loaded at runtime.

Using -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=ON can get the libraries, but I am not sure where I should put this and how to later use the libraries so they get linked.
Something like this:

ldd bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffffb1084000)
        libLLVM.so      => /myllvm/libLLVM.so.0 (0x0000ffffbxxxxxx)
        libMLIR.so      => /mymlir/libMLIR.so.0 (0x0000ffffbxxxxxx)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000ffffb1011000)
        libm.so.6       => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000ffffb0f40000)
        libdl.so.2      => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000ffffb0f1f000)
        librt.so.1      => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000ffffb0efe000)
        libstdc++.so.6  => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000ffffb0d1b000)
        libgcc_s.so.1   => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffffb0cf6000)
        libc.so.6       => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffffb0b60000)
        /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffffb1046000)


This is how I would do it:
I will make sure that the LLVM and MLIR are configured correctly for shared libraries:
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=ON - 
DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=ON -DLLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF 
<my_llvm_source_directory>
make

Now in my bazel build I would need to share the links for these libraries by creating a custom .bazelrc file to set these paths globally:
build -- 
action_env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/llvm/lib:/path/to/my/mlir/lib
build --define=llvm_shared=1


but I am not sure where I should put this and how to later use the libraries so they get linked.

The answer for this is the build files where LLVM and MLIR are included. make sure the build rules are set for linking by using linkshared = True,
Now I should be able to compile by using:
bazel build --config=opt 
//tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server

Note: This is not a tested solution, rather it shows how a general approach will look like.
Hope this helps you.

the linkshared = True, can be added to the rules where you create your binary files.
